# How to use MongoDB Search Index / Indexes on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection of 10 000 documents, (~ 6 Mb)

When I'm using a simple find to retrieve all the data, it takes like more than a minute to retrieve all the documents.

I created a search Index on MongoDb to speed up what I want to achieve.

[image]

I have also a search Index :

[image]

Here is the Query Syntax of this  Search Index :

```
new BsonArray {
  new BsonDocument("$search", new BsonDocument {
    {
      "index",
      "searchProd"
    },
    {
      "text",
      new BsonDocument {
        {
          "query",
          application // DYNAMIC Value that I want to pass
        },
        {
          "path",
          new BsonDocument("wildcard", "*")
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Couldn't find a way how to implement this on my function.

```
public async Task<List<Produit>> ListAllProducts(string application)
{
    var sw   = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var allProducts =  await _produits.Find(new BsonDocument("$search", new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "index",
            "searchProd"
        },
        {
            "text",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "query",
                    application
                },
                {
                    "path",
                    new BsonDocument("wildcard", "*")
                }
            }
        }
    })).ToList();
    return  allProducts;

}
```

By doing this I'm getting

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find failed: unknown top
> level operator: $search. If you have a field name that starts with a
> '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

atlas `$search` is an aggregation stage, not `find` argument. It should look similar to:

```
 _produits.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>("your $search stage in string or BsonDocument form").ToList();
```